# I need to take form data from react, and post it to my server to use as my query variable. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, api, axios

I am transitioning into full stack, and its a lot of fun. I am getting stuck at how to get my variable from client side to server side to use it to query the API. Any Tutorials or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. This concept is giving me the business, I just haven't got it yet.

```
////server.js
app.get("/getmovies", (req, res) => {
const {name} = req.body;

  request(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=${name}&apikey=${API_KEY}`,
      function (error, response, body) {
          if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
              var parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
              res.send(parsedBody)

          } else {
              console.log("error in the server")
          }
      }

  )
})

//client side
state = {
  movies: null,
  movie: {
    name: ''
  }
}


postJson = (e) => {
  const { movie } = this.state;
  e.preventDefault();
  axios.post(`/getmovies`, {})

    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      console.log(res.data);
    }
    )
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
}


getMovies = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  axios.get(`/getmovies`)

    .then(response => this.setState({ movies: response.data }))
    // .then(response => this.setState({ movies: response.data }))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Client Side

***POST***

You can pass the request body like this:

```
axios.post('/postmovies', {
  name: 'Fred',
}).then({
// ...
```

Or like this:

```
axios({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/postmovies',
  data: { name: 'Fred' },
}).then({
// ...
```

***GET***

You can simply pass the query param along with the URL, like this:

```
const { name } = this.state;
axios.get(`/getmovies?name=${name}`).then({
// ...
```

Check examples [here](https://github.com/axios/axios).

### Server Side

**Query Params**

For receiving query params, you can do:

```
app.get("/getmovies", (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.params;
  // ...
```

**Request Body**

For retrieving request body:

```
app.post("/postmovies", (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.body;
  // ...
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly what I was talking about! So can I use the .get(/getmovies${variable}) all in one api? I guess I am asking do I need multiple routes for this, or just 1 route to pass all this in and fetch it back?

Comment: As I posted, GET and POST are two different [http verbs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods), and you need to create two separate methods. If not, how can you know whether it's a write or a read call?

Comment: Also, if you think this is helpful, please express your feeling, by accepting and/or upvoting it.

Comment: I am so confused, I am sure it will click in my head eventually and I will realize how dumb I was. Thanks for your help